# Prove Euler's formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

If $F(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$, prove the Euler's formula.

$$XF_X+YF_Y+ZF_Z=nF$$

Could you give me a hint how we could show this?

**EDIT**: Could we show it like that?

Let $F(x,y,z)=\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} \ x^i \ y^j \ z^k$
$$F_x(x,y,z)=\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} i x^{i-1} y^j z^k$$

$$xF_x(x,y,z)=x\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} i x^{i-1} y^j z^k=\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} i x^{i} y^j z^k$$

$$yF_x(x,y,z)=y\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} x^{i}j y^{j-1} z^k=\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk}  x^{i} j y^j z^k$$

$$zF_x(x,y,z)=z\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk} x^{i} y^{j} k z^{k-1}=\sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ijk}  x^{i}  y^j k z^k$$

$$xF_x+yF_y+zF_z=(i+j+k) \sum_{i+j+k=n} a_{ij} x^i y^j z^k=nF$$

Comment: Does $F_{X} (F_{Y}, F_{Z}$ respectively) denote the formal derivative with respect to $X$?

Comment: Yes, that's what is meant..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: prove that it is true for a monomial $X^iY^jZ^k$ of degree $n=i+j+k$, and that both sides are linear in $F$.

Comment: BrunoJoyal Why does it stand that if it is true for a monomial $X^iY^jZ^k$, it is also true for any polynomial $F(X,Y,Z)$ ?

Comment: Since taking de derivative is linear and multiplication is distributive.

Comment: I edited my post... Could you tell me if it is right?

Comment: @evinda Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal But why do we take such a polynomial? Why doesn't it have for example a constant term?

Comment: @evinda Homogeneous polynomials are to projective space what polynomials are to affine space.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Could you explain it further to me?